# Creating array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm using Swift to create an array that needs to match this format:

```
let items = [["1", "red", "33", "canada"], ["2", "blue", "66", "usa"]]
```

In my code, I query a database and have multiple rows returned with the pertinent info:

```
let items = [id+" - "+colour+" - "+number+" - "+home_location]
```

I use a loop to `.append` the array but the format comes out like this instead:

```
["1 - red - 33 - canada", "2 - blue - 66 - usa"]
```

What do I need to do to create the required array structure?

Answer (score 2):

For each row of the database, instead of

```
let items = [id+" - "+colour+" - "+number+" - "+home_location]
```

say

```
let items = [id, colour, number, home_location]
```

Now append that to a `var` array of `[[String]]`.

Comment: I would also rename `items` to `item`. :)

Answer (score 0):

create model for your data like this

```
class ModelClass {

    var id = ""
    var colour = ""
    var number = ""
    var home_location = ""

}
```

and then create the object of your model class like this

```
let objmodel : ModelClass = ModelClass()
 objmodel.id = "1"
 objmodel.colour = "red"
 objmodel.number = "33"
 objmodel.home_location = "canada"
```

then create your main array and append this model object to your model array

```
var arrData = [ModelClass]()
arrData.append(objmodel)
```

Comment: 1. Your class should be a struct. 2. Class and struct names should start with uppercase letters. 3. `arrData` needs to be `var`, not `let`.  4. Let Swift determine a variable's type. Just do `var arrData = [ModelClass]()`.